# How do I get the output from a hex string to print in hex?

Tags: python, hex

How do I get the output from this hex string to print in hex?

It should be printing to bytes on every line like

```
31c0
5068
etc
```

Here's the code:

```
$ cat hex.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

hexstr = ("\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80")

x=bytearray(hexstr)

for i in xrange(0,len(x),2):
  print format(x[i:i+2]).decode('hex')
```

This is the error I get:

```
$ python  hex.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hex.py", line 8, in <module>
    print format(x[i:i+2]).decode('hex')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

Comment: You don't have a hex string. You have a Python bytestring. Perhaps you were looking for `binascii.hexlify()`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a hex string. You have a regular Python string defined with `\xhh` hex escape codes.

If you wanted to display these bytes as hex, all you have to do is encode them with the `hex` codec:

```
>>> hexstr = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"
>>> hexstr.encode('hex')
'31c050682f2f7368682f62696e89e35089e25389e1b00bcd80'
```

An alternative method is to use the [`binascii.hexlify()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) for the same result.

If you need each byte on a separate line, just loop over the string and encode individual characters (bytes):

```
>>> for c in hexstr:
...     print c.encode('hex')
... 
31
c0
50
68
2f
2f
73
68
68
2f
62
69
6e
89
e3
50
89
e2
53
89
e1
b0
0b
cd
80
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, that style worked (this prints 2 bytes per line): 
for i in xrange(0,len(x),2):
  print (x[i:i+2]).encode('hex')